# DRF : Generic way to inject additional info into request.data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I'm in a situation where I have a endpoint `samples` which represents a model `sample` via a `ModelViewSet`.

My goal is, that when a user POST's against this endpoint with data

like

```
{
    "a":1,
    "b":2 ,
    "c":3
}
```

i want to be able to override/add  key:value pairs to this incoming payload stored in `request.data` within the `create` method.

This can not be done by simply accessing `request.data` since it's a `QueryDict` which is immutable.

Furthermore i can not achieve this in the `perform_create()` method since the data i might inject is validation-critical.

Currently I'm stuck with the following solution which requires me to REWRITE the complete `create()` method :

```
class MyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Sample.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MSampleSerializer
    name = "samples"

    def add_info(self, request):
        ...
        <acquire_info>
        ...
        data = request.data.dict()
        data["s"] = <info1>
        data["r"] = <info1>
        data["t"] = <info1>
        return data


    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = self.add_info(request)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(
            serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers
        )
```

1. Is there a generic way to edit the `request.data` before any action method, like `create()` or `put()`, is called ?
2. If not 1.); is there a different possibility ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better for you to do this in a django middleware instead?  https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/18/how-to-create-a-custom-django-middleware.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.to_representation()` or `.to_internal_value()` methods of a serializer if you don't want to rewrite the whole view every time.

And since you want to validate the data too, `.to_representation()` might be the way to go about it.

From the docs:

> If you need to alter the serialization or deserialization behavior of a serializer class, you can do so by overriding the `.to_representation()` or `.to_internal_value()` methods.
>
> `.to_representation(self, obj)` takes the object instance that requires serialization, and should return a primitive representation. Typically this means returning a structure of built-in Python datatypes. The exact types that can be handled will depend on the render classes you have configured for your API.

Example:

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    """Convert `username` to lowercase."""
    ret = super().to_representation(instance)
    ret['username'] = ret['username'].lower()
    return ret
```

See [Advanced serializer usage: Overriding serialization and deserialization behavior](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior)

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it seems that i cannot access the request object within `to_internal_value()` which i need to do in this case.

Comment: Do you need the request object to access `request.data`? I think you can get them in `instance` or `ret` (from example). Let's try printing those two.

Comment: Pls excuse me, my answer was a bit to hasty. I was just copy-pasting my code from the Viewset into the serializer. The `request`object is stored in `self.context["request"]` within the serializer which did the trick. To your comment : No i do not need the request object for acces `data` or `instance` but for the ` <acquire_info>` part which i did not specify in my original question.